# cant access tty:job control turned off After dist-upgrade

Tags: debian, tty

i cannot boot my server anymore

[image]

what is the problem
plz help

Comment: something wrong with the rootfs. missing module or any other problem.

Comment: @IporSircer so ?

Comment: use a rescue live linux and examine the problem.

Answer (score 1):

initramfs is what loads before your root filesystem is mounted and things actually start going. Your system hasn't managed to get very far.

This message probably means your root filesystem which resides on LVM is gone for some reason:

```
/dev/mapper/srv1-root doesn't exist.
```

Debian has a rescue mode that helps you a little bit but you need to do some work yourself. Look into the missing LVM issue.

https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/amd64/ch08s07.html.en

There's not much else to say until you can provide more information. Who knows, maybe you're lucky and your hard drive is just unplugged? :)